# Fluid simulation - Domain, i don't have the options

Tags: fluid-simulation

I don't see any of this option in my blender file. I'm trying to make a fluid all over the skull inside the cube.

I tried many tutorials, but I don`t have the options for any of that

[image]

[image]

Comment: Because tut is from 2.9 with Mantaflow solver and your blender is 2.8 that use blenders fluid solver. Update Blender :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! i did not paid attention on this detail.. i feel a bit stupid for this question :)) , cheers!

Comment: In peace :) All of us do these small mistakes with big impact :)